# Reorganizing Item / Materia / Summon Arrangement on Battle Menu in Final Fantasy 7

Tags: final-fantasy-7

So, in Final Fantasy VII (on PC), most characters have a huge amount of blank space when you bring up their menus in battle.  This means that even if your character only has one summons materia, you have to scroll all the way down the character's menu to find that option, then select it.

This takes time in battle.  I know you can rearrange the items, by going to the 'item' menu outside of battle, and selecting 'Arrange'.  What is the comparable option for the materia, summons, et cetera.

Scrolling through a lot of empty spaces takes time.  I want my most-used materia to be at the top of the list, and any available summons to be at the top of its respective list.

Comment: From what I remember there is no way to fix this, its just part of the game, there should be a key that brings you to the next available selection through all the white space.

Comment: You can use L+R triggers (Page Up or Page Down on PC) to jump up or down the list a whole screen at a time if scrolling takes too long.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR there is no such functionality. Ability/magic/summon lists are fixed arrays of skills that are simply hidden unless you have the prerequisite materia equipped (thus the big empty spaces between skills). This is a shortcoming in the design... even if they didn't implement a system for the user to rearrange skills (which would have taken some effort to do), they very, very easily could have just implemented a filter to cut the menu size to only the available skills (instead of leaving all the white spaces), so I can really only assume that this was something they just overlooked in the rush to get the game out back in '97.